# Frequently getting attacks on admin-ajax.php, wp-cron.php, xmlrpc.php and wp-login.php

Tags: security

I am running more than 500 WordPress website in my shared server, Frequently I am getting attacks on **admin-ajax.php, wp-cron.php, xmlrpc.php and wp-login.php** files. Due to that our server load is getting more than 100.

Is there is any way to avoid the spamming request to this respective file.

hits are coming from 1000s of IP addresses from various countries and different ranges, So blocking them is not easy.

Currently I am blocking those file in .htaccess, Apart of from this I need any alternative solution.

Comment: fail2ban is a fairly simple solution: when you get lots of failures from the same source IP it gets turned into a temporary IP-level traffic block. I'd expect most WordPress security plugins will have something similar too.

Comment: I too have the same problem, attack is coming from too many IP addresses from various countries. I am also looking for solution for this kind of problem.

Comment: and how do you know that you are being "attacked"? and that it is related to the CPU spike?

Comment: @Rup IMHO fail2ban like any other IP based security solution is a bad idea. Attackers use bot networks that have different IPs, and you have many users which are sitting behind NAT (a real life usual thing for me is to be soft blocked by cloudflare when I sit in a coffeeshop)

Comment: @Mark Kaplun using top command, you can find out, 1000+ hits coming to those pages. may be someone is trying brute force login attempt to wp-admin

Comment: @Mani that do not mean there is a correletion. `cron.php` should not overload your CPU while `admin-ajax.php` might cause it because of bad coding not because of "attack". `xmlrpc.php` should be disabled in .htaccess in any case as it is useless, but before disabling the rest I would suggest to have better idea what is actually causing the high CPU as disabling any of them in the wrong way might cause loss of some functionality

Comment: The issue with varying ip addresses is a pain, but not unsolvable. We've written a security plugin (Shield Security) that tracks all of these sorts of requests and the IPs and blocks them as necessary. But it will automatically delete old IPs and keep your IP block table small so it won't balloon up on you. 1000s of IPs isn't a problem. Not automating their management is the problem.

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/135248/why-are-xmlrpc-php-and-wp-cron-php-being-called-so-often